# Using curly brace { as an input to tcsh Linux script

Tags: linux, tcsh, curly-braces

This question is regarding tcsh scripting in Linux. Suppose I want the user to enter a username and a password and then let the script check them both. If the user has a curly brace { in his password, the script won't work at all by claiming:

Missing }.

Is there a way to overcome this? Is there a way to start the script anyway so it will handle the curly brace from the inside?

Thanks, Poly

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're reading input with $<, quote the substitution:

```
set password = $<:q
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the viewers and dave sines for answering.

The answer is:

If you are using $argv it will fail.

If you use "$argv" it will work.

So, if an argument can contain a curly brace { then use double quotes to wrap $argv in order to read it correctly.

Poly

Answer (score 0):

In csh, **2 single quotes** can be used to protect (escape) curly braces. You may need one double quote (") when you echo the variable:

```
set a=''{''
echo "$a"
```

If you use curly braces (or brackets, [ ]) in a script, you can combine echo within back-quotes () and the escaped brackets:

```
set b = " COMMANDS `echo ''{''` MORE COMMANDS `echo ''}''` "
echo "$b"
```